# How to dynamically shrink or grow panel contents?

Tags: python, wxwidgets, boxsizer

I have an issue with making my program panel fit into a low resolution. Like if I have a resolution of 800 x 600, and my panel is larger than that, so everything gets cut off, especially the buttons that are on the bottom of the screen.

So, I made a mock program as an example:

```
import wx

MAIN_FRAME_SIZE = (190, 150)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):  

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id = -1, title = 'Hello, World!', size = MAIN_FRAME_SIZE)

        vertBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)   

        staticText = wx.StaticText(self, label = 'Hello, World!')

        vertBox.Add(staticText, 0, wx.ALL, 40)

        self.SetSizer(vertBox)       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

So, then my question is how do I make the 'Hello, World!' text larger when the MainFrame gets larger, and how do I do the same when the MainFrame gets smaller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can select your font size depending on the frame size using some heuristics or you can compute the length of your string using `GetTextExtent()` and find the font size for which it will be equal to what you want.

To do this dynamically when the frame is resized, you need to catch `wxEVT_SIZE` and change the font in its handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the static text was just used as an example. In my actual program, I have all types and kinds of widgets in it... so it seems hard for me to imagine how to resize all of these on the fly.

Comment: It's very unusual to change the font of the controls on the fly like this. Typically you use sizers for the layout, but sizers change the size of the window, so that e.g. your text control could show more text. They never change the size of the font.

Comment: P.S. And by "unusual" I really mean "unheard of".